# Getting values from Kirki customizer fields in WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the [Kirki plugin](https://kirki.org/) to add fields and sections in the WordPress customizer. So far, I can get a field to be added to the customizer, but I'm confused on how to return that data back into my theme. I'm kinda tired so I might be missing something. This is what I have so far:

```
Kirki::add_config('theme_config_id', array(
  'capability'    => 'edit_theme_options',
  'option_type'   => 'theme_mod',
));

Kirki::add_section('footer_section', array(
  'title'          => __('Footer'),
  'description'    => __('Add custom footer here'),
  'panel'          => '', // Not typically needed.
  'priority'       => 160,
  'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
  'theme_supports' => '', // Rarely needed.
));


Kirki::add_field('theme_config_id', [
  'type'        => 'editor',
  'settings'    => 'my_setting',
  'label'       => esc_html__('Footer Content', 'kirki'),
  'description' => esc_html__('This content will show in the footer.', 'kirki'),
  'section'     => 'footer_section',
  'default'     => '',
]);
```

I was reading on trying to the values out [from here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/toolbox-of-the-smart-wordpress-developer-kirki--cms-23739) using this:

```
$value = Kirki::get_option( $config_id, $option_id );
```

But I'm not sure where (or what) the `$config_id` or `$option_id` would be?
I have a feeling that I'm missing something and I've read through the docs and I feel that I'm not getting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct code

```
$value = Kirki::get_option( 'config_id', 'option_id' );
```

so in your case,

```
$value = Kirki::get_option( 'theme_custom', 'footer_content' );
```

Comment: Ah, cool, thanks! I'll have to check that as well. Strange that it works outright, but I'll swap this in once I get a moment.

Answer (score 1):

After digging through the internet a little bit, I was able to read through some more documentation as well as some other examples and I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong. Overall, I was close, but I ended up cleaning it up and just using the WordPress `get_theme_mod()` outright in my template file (in this case it was the `footer.php` file).

Here's what I ended up with:

```
Kirki::add_config('theme_custom', array(
  'capability'    => 'edit_theme_options',
  'option_type'   => 'theme_mod'
));

Kirki::add_section('footer_section', array(
  'title'          => __('Footer'),
  'description'    => __('Add custom footer here'),
  'panel'          => '', // Not typically needed.
  'priority'       => 160,
  'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
  'theme_supports' => '', // Rarely needed.
));


Kirki::add_field('theme_custom', array(
  'type'        => 'editor',
  'settings'    => 'footer_content',
  'label'       => esc_html__('Footer Content', 'kirki'),
  'description' => esc_html__('This content will show in the footer.', 'kirki'),
  'section'     => 'footer_section',
  'default'     => '',
  'priority'    => 10
));
```

and in my `footer.php` file, I added this:

```
<?php $value = get_theme_mod('footer_content', ''); ?>
<?php echo($value); ?>
```

Granted, this is a *super* basic way of implementing this. I'm going to try and figure out how to get it to refresh the customizer preview before you publish it. But for now, this seems to be working.